# How to add number to awk array elements?

Tags: bash, awk

If I have the following bash variable:

```
$ echo "${pos}"

201
719
744
205
354
```

...the following produces...

```
!#bin/bash
(
    IFS=: 
    awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="[$IFS]" '
        BEGIN {
            m = split(str2, b, sep)
            for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {print b[i]}
        }
    '
)

-----------------
$ ./myscript.sh

201
719
744
205
354
```

...but then doing...

```
(
    IFS=: 
    awk -v str2="$pos" -v sep="[$IFS]" '
        BEGIN {
            m = split(str2, b, sep)
            for (i=1; i<=m; ++i) {print b[i]+10}
        }
    '
)

------
./myscript.sh

211
```

...so the addition is working, but not printing results for all elements. Why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is your IFS=: not set properly. So split() does not fill the array with values but fills it it with one value the str2, so in your for loop you print b[i] but actually you print once b[1] which is your entire str2 and because it has new lines you think it prints members of array b, but if you check m the retrn value of split() it is 1. Remove IFS=: and your script should work properly.

Comment: thank you so much. this worked. the fact that b[1] appears to be b[i] was what was confusing me and thank you for pointing this out.